# Java xml bind element hook

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, lombok

I wonder if is possible to convert a xml file that uses element hook, into java object.

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<personControl>
    <personList>
        <person>
            <name>John</name>
            <lastName>Doe</lastName>
            <fullName>${lastName} ${name}</fullName>
        </person>
        ...
    </personList>
</personControl>
```

Java classes:

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement
public class PersonControl {
    private PersonList personList;
}

@Data
public class PersonList {
    private List<Person> person;
}

@Data
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String fullName;
}
```

To be simple, I need field concatenation, is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found the answer for my question, I'll post here, maybe someone will consider useful.

I was using the java implementation, that does not have the cyclic reference implementation.

I changed it for the X-Stream implementation.

http://x-stream.github.io/graphs.html

As you can see, X-Stream implements the cyclic reference:

```
<list>
  <cd>
    <id>maria rita</id>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <id>basement_jaxx_singles</id>
  </cd>
  <cd reference="/list/cd[2]"/>
  <list reference="/list"/>
</list>
```